# Tight black box around chapter titles?

Tags: sectioning, xetex, memoir, soul

I am looking to make a tight black box around my chapter titles, ideally only `1pt` of margin on each side. So far, my best results have been with `soul`:

[image: using "soul" package]

However, you'll notice that there is too much margin at the bottom. Also, the highlight gets repeated at the top of each odd page:

[image: using "soul" package]

What is the clever way to do this stuff? I don't mind using something else than `soul`, it just seemed like a good solution.

MWE below. Please note that you'll need the [Mikodacs](http://www.glukfonts.pl/font.php?font=Mikodacs) font (or perhaps any TTF font?) in `FONTLOCATION`.

```
\documentclass[book,dvipsnames]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{soul}
\sethlcolor{black}

%% Change height of highlight
\makeatletter
 \def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
 \setul{}{2ex}%
 \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
 \SOUL@stpreamble
 }
\makeatother

\newfontfamily{\archivo}[Path=/FONTLOCATION]{Mikodacs.ttf}

\usepackage{lipsum} %% For dummy text

%% Chapterstyle
\makechapterstyle{lucknerto}{%
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-2\onelineskip}%
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{2\onelineskip}%
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}%
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}%
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}%
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}%
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}{\centering\archivo\color{White}\fontsize{23}{27.6}\selectfont\MakeUppercase}
}
\chapterstyle{lucknerto} %% enable

%% Pagestyle 
\makepagestyle{luckner}%
\makeevenhead{luckner}{}{\small{{\MakeUppercase{book title}}}}{} 
\makeoddhead{luckner}{}{\small{{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}}}{}
\makeevenfoot{luckner}{\large{\thepage}}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{luckner}{}{}{\large{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{luckner} %% enable

\begin{document}
\chapter{\hl{Foobar}}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tcolorbox` can provide nice (and tight) boxes

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, how would you implement it? I tried

`\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=black]
\chapter{Foobar}
\end{tcolorbox}`

... but that ruins the pagestyle.

Comment: I'll try but your document is not compilable, due to the XeLaTeX stuff ;-) I just don't have the font and must replace it :-(

Comment: It *is* compilable? I just tested it ...

Comment: No, it isn't. I don't have your Mikodacs font

Comment: Then use another TTF font or download it?

Comment: I included it because the inclusion of TTF fonts seems to sometimes trigger unexpected results ...

Comment: I've answered the question (I think), but the Mikodacs font is ... well... awful ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style is pretty easy with `tcolorbox` and a special `\tcbox` command for this, which is can be modified to the personal preferences.

The 'difficulty' is to understand what `memoir` does with the chapter title. I had to change `\printchaptertitle` to have an argument (which is the usual case), other than to work with moving arguments.

```
\documentclass[book,dvipsnames]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\sethlcolor{black}

%% Change height of highlight
\makeatletter
 \def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
 \setul{}{2ex}%
 \let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
 \SOUL@stpreamble
 }
\makeatother

\newfontfamily{\archivo}[Path=/FONTLOCATION]{Micodacs.ttf}

%\newfontfamily{\archivo}{Liberation Sans}

\usepackage{lipsum} %% For dummy text

\tcbset{chapterhead/.style={%
    fontupper=\archivo\fontsize{23}{27.6}\selectfont,
    left skip=1ex, % for example
    nobeforeafter, %no spacing before and after the box etc
    halign=center, % horizontal align within box, can be omitted
    valign=center, % vertical align within box, can be omitted
    colback=black, % black background colour
    size=tight, % tight box
    colupper=white, % white foreground colour
  }
}

\newtcbox{\blackbox}[1][]{%
  chapterhead,
  #1,
}

%% Chapterstyle
\makechapterstyle{lucknerto}{%
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-2\onelineskip}%
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{2\onelineskip}%
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}%
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}%
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}%
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}%
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}{\centering\tcbox[nobeforeafter,halign=center,valign=center,colback=black,size=tight,colupper=white,code={\noexpand\MakeUppercase}]}%\centering\archivo\color{blue}\fontsize{23}{27.6}\selectfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\centering\blackbox{\MakeUppercase{##1}}}%\centering\archivo\color{blue}\fontsize{23}{27.6}\selectfont\MakeUppercase}
}
\chapterstyle{lucknerto} %% enable

%% Pagestyle 
\makepagestyle{luckner}%
\makeevenhead{luckner}{}{\small{{\MakeUppercase{book title}}}}{} 
\makeoddhead{luckner}{}{\small{{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}}}{}
\makeevenfoot{luckner}{\large{\thepage}}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{luckner}{}{}{\large{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{luckner} %% enable

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foobar}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Output with Mikodacs font:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Only small comment is that there seems to be a white border to the box, can this be fixed?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard: `colframe=black` as option to the box or in the `chapterhead` style for the box (that's the easiest way, I think)

Comment: Splendid! Gracias!